# Check if Excel file has "Sheet protection" or "Custom defined properties in cells"

Tags: c#, excel

Given an Excel(*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm) file, is it possible to read its properties and find out if any of the worksheets are protected or if any of the cells have custom defined properties.

I was not able to find which libary to use for this purpose.

I need to know this information so that based on it I can then decide to show a Preview of the Excel file using Office Web Apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can analyse and modify the modern "Open XML" (*.xlsx) formats using the  [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx).

Here is an example on how find out if a sheet is protected:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

class Test
{

    static void Main()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\MyProtectedSheet.xlsx";
        using (var spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
        {
            var workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            var sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
            var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            var workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            var protections = worksheet.Elements<SheetProtection>(); 

            if(protections.Any())) {
                Console.WriteLine("Sheet is protected.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finding custom defined properties is also possible using the SDK. I would suggest that you open a minimal example file with the `OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool`
 (part of the SDK) and find the relevant tags/attributes. Then you can follow the pattern from the above example and try to locate them in the document tree.

Dealing with the legacy formats like `*.xls` is a lot harder. You could use COM automation to find out about the protection, but that requires an installation of Excel on the machine your code is supposed to run. Alternatively, you could resort to a commercial third party component like [Apose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then open a file and get a range (with file.range). In

```
range.locked
```

you can find, if the cells are locked. There are also other members which could be useful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_members(VS.80).aspx